# Filtering/Sorting in excel from selected names

Tags: excel, sorting, filtering

I am about to write my Bachelor thesis and I am struggeling to Filter my data

So far the only solution I have in mind is to manually select the wanted ID's. But i hope some of you have an smarter solution as it would take me several hours to click the filter manually.

My dataset contains 193.522 rows and 14 colums

Snapshot of dataset

[image]

and i have carefully listed specific fund-names to examine as they contain no empty datacells.

Selected fund-names

[image]

So my question is, is it possible to filter the entire column (Fund name) by the list given in the picture of selected fund names?

I appreciate your help

/JernJens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the following code as requierd.
Pay attention to the comments added and make sure all the sheets exists in the workbook and sheet names are changed accordingly.

```
Sub FilterBachelorThesis()
Dim arrFilters
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Fund Names")     'Sheet with list of Fund Names
        'Assuming your list of fund names on FundNames Sheet in column A starting from Row2
        arrFilters = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))
    End With

    'Assuming you have a Sheet called "Filter Data" to hold the filtered result
    Worksheets("Filtered Data").UsedRange.ClearContents

    'Data is the main sheet which contains all your data
    With Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter 5, arrFilters, 7
        .Copy Worksheets("Filtered Data").Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` function

Open a new column and add below formula. The formula will indicate if the relevant fund exist in your fund list to be filtered.

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(E:E,RangeForFundstoFilter,0))
```

Then filter with `TRUE` or `FALSE`